# L'Hospital's Rule Indeterminate Form Question

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit, but I don't know if I can use L'Hopital's Rule on it in the current form.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\ln ({3n+1}) - \ln ({3n-1}) \over \frac 1n} $$

I tried to look what $\infty - \infty$ is equal to, but it seems that it varies based on what type of infinity these are, so that didn't help. If this doesn't work I don't see any other way to get it into a form that works, but if I am wrong pointers in the right direction would be useful.

Please don't solve the problem for me, this the middle of a homework problem so I am trying to figure this out at least partially on my own. Thanks

Comment: You should begin with  exploiting the properties of logarithm in the numerator.

Comment: Chang the top into a single logarithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT :**

Use the subtraction property of logarithm for the expression in the numberator and you'll get :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\ln ({3n+1}) - \ln ({3n-1}) \over \frac 1n}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\bigg(\frac{3n+1}{3n-1}\bigg)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now this is an intermediate form of $\frac{0}{0}$ when $x \to \infty$ so you can proceed with applying L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Does the numerator of the limit equal 0 because $3n-1$ and $3n+1$ both grow at the same rate so ${\infty \over \infty} = 1$? Because I thought ${\infty \over \infty}$ is an indeterminate form? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dumbitdownjr Noting it as $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$ is wrong. The general idea behind it is that indeed both the numerator and the denominator grow at the same rate (because of $3n$) as you mentioned correctly. Specifically, as a rule, if you have $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $f(x),g(x)$ are polynomials, then the limit is given at the higher order terms. In this case : $$\frac{3n}{3n} = 1$$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @dumbitdownjr My pleasure !

Answer (score 3):

*Just another way*

As Rebellos answered
$$A=\lim_{x \to \infty} {\ln ({3n+1}) - \ln ({3n-1}) \over \frac 1n}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\bigg(\frac{3n+1}{3n-1}\bigg)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\bigg(1+\frac{2}{3n-1}\bigg)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Now, using equivalents
$$\ln\bigg(1+\frac{2}{3n-1}\bigg)\sim \frac{2}{3n-1}$$ making 
$$A\sim \frac{2n}{3n-1}\to \,\,?$$

Comment: I like this way of doing things; did you use polynomial division to go from ${3n+1 \over 3n-1}$ to $1 + {2 \over 3n-1}$, or some other way? Also, when I looked up equivalents it seems to be the end behavior of a limit as it approaches infinity, so I'm wondering do you usually use this when you are doing math problems or only for formal proofs. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also not use L'Hospital rule doing as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(3n+1)-\ln(3n-1)}{1/n}&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3n+1}{3n-1}\right)^{n}\\&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{3n}}{1-\frac{1}{3n}}\right)^{n}\\&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{n}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{n}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now use that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{\alpha}{n}\right)^n=e^\alpha$.

Comment: The OP asked to not solve the exercise for him though.

Comment: That is ok, it is a different way than I am doing it anyway. However, I am confused about the step after you joined the logs together into a fraction. How did you transform the numerator and the denominator like that?

Comment: +1, but you flipped the numerator and denominator

Answer (score 2):

By [Taylor's series for natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Taylor_series&action=edit&section=9)

$$\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$$

we have

$${\ln ({3n+1}) - \ln ({3n-1}) \over \frac 1n} = n\left(\ln \left(1+\frac1{3n}\right) - \ln \left(1-\frac1{3n}\right)\right)=n\left(\frac1{3n}+\frac1{3n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac23+o(1)\to\frac23$$

Comment: Wow, how do you guys think of stuff like this? impressive

Comment: @dumbitdownjr just to try to make the derivation a little bit different, there are many ways as you can see